# Creating a local Fedora repository with anonymous rsync

Tags: linux, repository, fedora

I am trying to create a local Fedora 13 repository in a local LAN network

Unfortunately I cannot run rsync in daemon mode because I'm behind a firewall on which I have no control. So I had to try using rsync over shell.

I tried the mirrors in http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist , I get prompted for passwords. I thought these were supposed to be anonymous access. What am I doing wrong?

Lets say I want to create a local repository for Fedora 13 i386 os, what command would I need to issue on my local system? It would be of immense help if someone could provide a working example.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You won't be allowed to SSH into a mirror.

You could use `wget` to mirror but http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Infrastructure/Mirroring#Mirroring says "The only sane way to do mirroring is to use rsync."

> I'm behind a firewall on which I have no control.

This is the problem you need to solve. If you are in a (sane) corporate environment then if you provide a business justification for having a local mirror then the firewall would be changed to allow the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile, but here's what I did to create a local repository on my network.

```
mkdir /repos

rsync -avuH --exclude=debug/ --exclude=drpms/ rsync://mirrors.reflected.net/fedora/linux/releases/11/Fedora/i386/os/Packages/ /repos/releases/11/i386/os/Packages/

rsync -avuH --exclude=debug/ --exclude=drpms/ rsync://mirrors.reflected.net/fedora/linux/updates/11/i386/ /repos/updates/11/i386/

createrepo -g /repos/releases/11/i386/os/repodata/comps.xml /repos/releases/11/i386/os/

createrepo -g /repos/updates/11/i386/repodata/comps-f11.xml /repos/updates/11/i386/
```

I don't recall offhand where I got the group files (comps.xml and comps-f11.xml).  I think I probably copied whatever was in http://mirrors.reflected.net/fedora/linux/releases/11/Everything/i386/os/repodata/ and changed the name to make it shorter.

Almost forgot, you should be able to just change 11 in my examples to 13.  Like I said, it's been awhile since I set this up.